# May @Repository annotation be inherited?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

May @Repository annotation be inherited?

May I create a

```
@Repository
public abstract class BaseRepository {
}
```

and then extend it without specifying @Repository annotation?

```
public class MyRepository extends BaseRepository {
}
```

How do I know if an annotation can be inherited?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.java.html

There is no @Inherited annotation, so it is not inherited.

Answer (score 6):

No. The [documentation about stereotypes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s12.html) says nothing about it.

Also, imagine the case when you specify a name `@Repository("foo")` - then each subclass will be named `foo`, which will lead to an exception (duplicate names)

Answer (score 2):

Annotations aren't inherited by subclasses by default, unless annotated themselves with @Inherited (see James Kingsbery's comment below), and even then only when they are used at class-level. @Repository-annotation itself is not annotated (I checked from the code) with @Inherited, so you'll have to annotate the subclass separately.

Comment: libraries tend to scan class hierarchies to see if an annotation is present. I believe the question is about whether spring does it.

Comment: that is not entirely true: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html... Annotations can be inherited, but they are not by default.

Comment: +1 @James Kingsbery: Thanks for pointing that out, this would have actually saved me from some trouble a while back... =P

Comment: Edited the answer to fit the question better.