# @Autowired cant find repository bean identified with @Repository

Tags: java, spring

If you cant find the bug at least say yes or no that i have carried out all the correct steps, that way at least I a can think that there is another error in my context xml file

The error is as follows

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [net.com.htts.transaction.service.mapping.FundService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I have a Junit test which cant load the a repository bean.

1) I created a interface FundRepository 
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped
package net.com.htts.transaction.data.repository;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;   
import net.com.htts.transaction.data.entity.Fund;   

@Repository  
public interface FundRepository {    
public void createFund(Fund fund);   
}  

package net.com.htts.transaction.data.repository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import net.com.htts.transaction.data.entity.Fund;

@Repository
public interface FundRepository { 
public void createFund(Fund fund);
}
```

The interface has the @Repository

2) I created the FundRepositoryImpl which implements my interface

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped
package net.com.htts.transaction.data.repository;

```
import java.util.List;   

import net.com.htts.transaction.data.entity.Fund;   

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;   
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;   
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;   

public class FundRepositoryImpl implements FundRepository{   

@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)   
private EntityManager entityManager;   

public void createFund(Fund fund) {   
    entityManager.persist(fund);   
}   
     }  
    package net.com.htts.transaction.data.repository;
import java.util.List;

import net.com.htts.transaction.data.entity.Fund;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

public class FundRepositoryImpl implements FundRepository{

@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void createFund(Fund fund) {
    entityManager.persist(fund);
}
}
```

Created the spring data context

in this context i added the following

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
           <!-- Scan the repositories -->   
<jpa:repositories base-package="net.com.htts.transaction.data.repository" />  
           <!-- Scan the data layer -->
<context:component-scan base-package="net.com.htts.transaction.data" />

           <!-- Scan the repositories -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="net.com.htts.transaction.data.repository" />
```

According to everything i have read this should be enough to allow me to @Autowired in FundRepository.

The Junit is as follows

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)   
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/spring/fund-test-data.xml")   
public class FundRepositoryTest {   

@Autowired    
 private FundRepository repository;   



@Test  
public void createFund(){   
}
```

}

The context is as follows

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
 class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">   
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />   
    <property name="packagesToScan">   
        <list>   
            <value>net.com.htts.transaction.data</value>   
            <value>net.com.htts.transaction.data.repository</value>   
        </list>   
    </property>   
     <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">   
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">   
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />   
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />   
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />   
        </bean>   
    </property>   
    <property name="jpaProperties">   
        <props>   
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>   
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">
        net.com.htts.transaction.data.naming.NamingStrategy</prop>   
        </props>   
    </property>   
</bean>   

<bean id="dataSource"  
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">   
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />   
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/funds" />   
    <property name="username" value="fund_user" />   
    <property name="password" value="fund_user" />   
</bean>   

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">   
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />   
</bean>   

<!-- Scan the data layer -->   
<context:component-scan base-package="net.com.htts.transaction.data" />   

<!-- Scan the repositories -->   
<jpa:repositories base-package="net.com.htts.transaction.data.repository" />   

</beans>
```

Answer (score 3):

Afaik the `@Repository` annotation must be present on the concrete implementation, not the interface. Spring will not find and instantiate your `FundRepositoryImpl`, as it is not marked with any of the component annotations. In general, annotations in java are **not** inherited. Some frameworks allow annotation inheritance through other means. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081942/may-repository-annotation-be-inherited).

Answer (score 0):

annotation do **not inherited**, you should use annotation in class that implemented  interface.
if you have to implementation you must use **@Qualifire**

Answer (score 0):

1) From your log snippet `No matching bean of type [net.com.htts.transaction.service.mapping.FundService]` indicates that the problem is with a definition of FundService somewhere in your project which I did not see anywhere in the presented sources.

Double check that you are indeed having problems with the repo and attach the appropriate log, or take a look at that service

2) If you want to simplify your code and avoid rewriting again the data access layer, you can take advantage of [spring data repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)