# I get an error "Consider defining a bean of type"

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Main Service class

```
@Service
public class MainService {

@Autowired
HouseRepository repository;

@Autowired
HouseDtoConverter converter;

public House addNewHouse(HouseDTO houseDTO) {

House h = converter.convert(houseDTO);
repository.save(h);

return h;``
}

public Iterable<House> getAllHouses() {
return repository.findAll();
 }
}
```

Main Controller class

```
@RestController    // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class MainController {

@Autowired
MainService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST) // Map ONLY GET Requests
@ResponseBody
public House addNewHouse (@RequestBody HouseDTO houseDTO) {
return service.addNewHouse(houseDTO);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Iterable<House> getAllHouses() {
// This returns a JSON or XML with the houses
return service.getAllHouses();
}
```

And the stack trace:
Description:

Field repository in vikings.service.MainService required a bean of type 'vikings.repository.HouseRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'vikings.repository.HouseRepository' in your configuration.

That's my SpringBootApplication

```
@Component
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBoot11Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBoot11Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an class of type `HouseRepository` annotated with `@Repository` or `@Service` or `@Component` in a scanned package?

Comment: HouseRepository  Class is not found in your case.Please create repository of HouseRepository  class

Comment: Here is my HouseRepository class

        `package vikings.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import vikings.model.House;

@Repository
public interface HouseRepository extends JpaRepository<House, Long> {
}
`

Comment: the `HouseRepository` is an interface, for creating a bean spring needs an implementation of the interface. If the implementation of `HouseRepository` exists and if is not a spring boot application, check if the package which contains the implementation of `HouseRepository` is included in any component scan defined in the configuration. Also the implementation of `HouseRepository` needs to be annotated with one of the annotations from my previous comment

Comment: Annotating `HouseRepository` interface with `@Repository` does not help as the `@Repository` annotation is not inherited (details on [May @Repository annotation be inherited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081942/may-repository-annotation-be-inherited) thread). The `@Repository` annotation needs to be on a class implementing `HouseRepository`

Comment: Make sure to have the needed packages installed

Comment: Add your package structure. The `SpringBoot11Application` should be in a top-level package which covers everything else. I suspect you have put it in a subpackage not detecting your other classes. Putting `@Repository` on an interface is useless as Spring Data JPA has other means of detecting those interfaces.